# customerror: cannot find module imported from

Tags: typescript

when I am using this command to build the project, shows error:

```
> npm run build
npm info using npm@9.6.7
npm info using node@v16.14.2
npm info found workspace root at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex 

> rd-lezer-tex@0.0.1 build
> NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm' gulp build

(node:82873) ExperimentalWarning: --experimental-loader is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
CustomError: Cannot find module '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex/packages/lezer-tex/src/utils/lzw' imported from /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex/packages/lezer-tex/gulpfile.ts
    at finalizeResolution (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:366:11)
    at moduleResolve (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:801:10)
    at Object.defaultResolve (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:912:11)
    at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:218:35
    at entrypointFallback (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:168:34)
    at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:217:14
    at addShortCircuitFlag (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:409:21)
    at resolve (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex/node_modules/ts-node/src/esm.ts:197:12)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:251:18)
npm ERR! Lifecycle script `build` failed with error: 
npm ERR! Error: command failed 
npm ERR!   in workspace: rd-lezer-tex@0.0.1 
npm ERR!   at location: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/codemirror-tex/packages/lezer-tex
```

seems the build process did not recognized the ts file type. why did this happen? this is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rd-lezer-tex",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "lezer-based TeX grammar",
  "keywords": [
    "lezer",
    "tex",
    "cm",
    "codemirror",
    "codemirror6",
    "cm6",
    "latex",
    "grammar",
    "language"
  ],
  "author": "mu.io <dev@mathematic.io>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/mu-io/codemirror-tex",
  "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
  "main": "./lib/index.cjs",
  "module": "./lib/index.js",
  "types": "./lib/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    "import": "./lib/index.js",
    "require": "./lib/index.cjs"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib"
  ],
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/mu-io/codemirror-tex.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "all": "gulp all",
    "docs": "gulp docs",
    "generate": "gulp generate",
    "build": "NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm' gulp build",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.2.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/gulp": "^4.0.8",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/lz-string": "^1.3.34",
    "@types/mustache": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.7",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "mustache": "^4.1.0",
    "rollup": "^2.41.3",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.3",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "yaml": "^1.10.2"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mu-io/codemirror-tex/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@lezer/lr": "^1.3.13",
    "lz-string": "^1.4.4"
  }
}
```

and this is the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.build.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "module": "ESNext",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "tests", "third_party"]
}
```

I have checked the import file exists, the import style look like this `import { lzwEncode } from './src/utils/lzw';`.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the answer from github issue: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/422. Add `"experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"` in ts-node will fix this issue, the configuration may look like this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.build.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "module": "ESNext",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    // https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/422
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node",
  },
  "include": ["src", "tests", "third_party"]
}
```